# What's the difference between "mirror" and "looking glass"?

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

I have read that a looking glass is a surface with sufficient reflection to form an image of an object... doesn't that sound like a mirror?

Comment: [looking glass](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/looking%2Bglass?q=looking+glass), [mirror](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mirror?q=mirror). These are the respective definitions for the words in question. Please read them and edit your question to further explain any misunderstanding you have.

Comment: This is yet another instance where a question is, at one level, general reference and, at another, not. In common usage today (according to standard dictionaries) the terms are interchangeable; but historically _mirror_ was a broader term, as my answer below attempts to document.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference. "Looking glass" is a poetic and archaic way to refer to a mirror.

Answer (score 5):

*Looking glass* was considered the 'proper' word to use when referring to what we now would all call a mirror. The word *mirror* was considered vulgar and middle-class by the upper classes. Some upper class people will still say *looking glass* instead of *mirror*. The word *glass* on its own also often refers to mirrors rather than glass. Hence *pier glass*, or 'go and look in the glass'.

Comment: +1: Here is some corroboration for your answer. [This page](http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2012/02/09/the-looking-glass-vs-mirror-war-language-and-class/) indeed says that *looking glass* was considered the 'proper' word (although only in the U.K.).

Comment: I would also like to further note that "looking glass" is far more common in the UK (and specifically England), as I have not heard anyone use the term in the US regardless of region or class (though I do not generally break bread with the upper crust, so perhaps it is not unheard of). I think if not for Lewis Carroll far fewer Americans would even have ever heard the term. +1 to you both.

Answer (score 3):

When Perseus slays Medusa, he does so without looking directly at her, instead using his highly polished shield as a mirror. This sense of *mirror* is reflected (so to speak) in the first definition of the term in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **mirror** 1: a polished or smooth surface (as of glass) that forms images for reflection

But would it be correct to say that Perseus used his shield as a looking glass? The underlying question here is, How literally should we take the component "glass" in the term *looking glass*? If looking glasses must be made, in part, of glass, then a metal shield can't be a looking glass, though it can be a mirror.

The *Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* isn't especially helpful on this point, as it defines *looking glass* simply as "MIRROR." Earlier dictionaries, however, don't treat the two terms as identical.

One of the clearest treatments of the differences between *mirror* and *looking-glass* appears in *Merriam-Webster's [First] International Dictionary of the English Language* (1890), which provides distinct definitions for three related terms:

> **Looking-glass** A mirror made of glass on which has been placed a backing of some reflecting substance, as quicksilver.
>
> **Mirror** A looking-glass or a speculum; any glass or polished substance that forms images by the reflection of rays of light.
>
> **Speculum 1.** A mirror, or looking-glass; especially a metal mirror, as in Greek and Roman archaeology. **2.** A reflector of polished metal, especially one used in reflecting telescopes. ...

From these definitions, it appears that (late in the nineteenth century, anyway) Perseus's shield would have qualified as both a mirror and a speculum, but not as a looking-glass.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between *looking glass* and *mirror* is that *looking glass*, when used as adjective, means *being or involving the opposite of what is normal or expected* (*a looking-glass land*, *looking-glass logic*); *mirror* can also be figuratively used to mean *something regarded as accurately representing something else* (*the stage is supposed to be the mirror of life*).

**<sub>[Reference: the New Oxford American Dictionary.]</sub>**

Comment: I don't know if I've ever encountered *looking glass* as an adjective.

Comment: I have, but it has always been an allusion to the world Lewis Carol created, where things are different ways than just being reversed left-to-right. It's not unlike telling folks that they are no longer in Kansas.

Comment: @Marthaª: From "Lucy in the Sky with Diamonds": "Picture yourself on a train in a station/With plasticine porters with **looking glass** ties/Suddenly someone is there at the turnstile/The girl with kaleidoscope eyes."

Answer (score 0):

A [looking glass](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1264308?rskey=04bPXG&result=2#m_en_us1264308.002) is indeed a mirror. As @JSBangs alluded to, it is only largely used in literary contexts. Two notable examples (book titles) are:

- [*Through the Looking-Glass*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Through_the_Looking-Glass) (Lewis Carroll)
- [*Into the Looking Glass*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Into_the_Looking_Glass) (John Ringo)

Comment: The page you link to mentions a difference in attributive use.

Comment: @msh210: Yes I know, but the asker specifically refers to the noun case.

Comment: So, the obvious difference is that you can't go into or through a mirror :)